# Populating wpf TreeView with specific XML structure

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, treeview

I searching around StackOverflow, but can't seem to find the answer. I'm new to WPF and I really get confused with xaml part. So how to make a structure like xml from below?

I'm trying to built a view for this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Patients>
  <Patient>
    <ID>44</ID>
    <Name>Ben Garsia</Name>
    <Year>1985</Year>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <ID>22</ID>
    <Name>Melisa Mayer</Name>
    <Year>1968</Year>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <ID>33</ID>
    <Name>Morgan Smith</Name>
    <Year>1979</Year>
  </Patient>
</Patients>
```

and want Treeview to be exactly like that, so first to have Patients as a node, then when I expand it, to have three node "Patient", and then Patient's related stuff.

Instead I get this:

```
Patients
  44Ben Garsia1985
  22Melisa Mayer1968
  33Morgan Smith1979
```

Here is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="LoadTreeView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoadTreeView"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TreeView Name="treeViewT">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PatientsList}" ItemsSource="{Binding Patients}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Patients" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Patient}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Year}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="btnLoad" Content="Load file" Width="100" Click="button_Click"  
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And classes I've used:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Patient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

}

[XmlRootAttribute("Patients")]
public class PatientsList
{
    [XmlElement("Patient")]
    public Patient[] Patients { get; set; }

}
```

In the code behind of xaml, I populate it like this:

```
var patientsList = new List<PatientsList>();
        patientsList.Add(patients);

        treeViewT.ItemsSource = patientsList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the DataTemplate for a patient to be a stackpanel with three TextBlocks, so that's what each node in the tree is showing.

Instead the DataTemplate should be just what you want the node to show, probably just a single text block for the name, maybe with an icon.

To add extra nodes for the other properties, the patient object needs to have a collection (ideally an ObservableCollection) of objects (which could just be strings) that can be the ItemSource for each Patient Node.

In general the TreeView should have an ItemSource for the top level node (PatientLists, in your example), and you define a HierarchicalDataTemplate for a Patient, which would have an ItemSource that points to their list of child nodes. You'd then define another HierarchicalDataTemplate (or just a DataTemplate) for each type of object in that list.

In your case, you'll probably need a PatientViewModel, which will expose an ObservableList of strings for their properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate class for the Tree binding (TreeViewModel).
Here is the code for a tree exactly like the XML.

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="treeViewT" ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel 
{

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Tree = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>();
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        var list1 = new PatientsList();
        list1.Patients.Add(new Patient { ID = 44, Name = "Ben Garsia", Year = 1985 });
        list1.Patients.Add(new Patient { ID = 22, Name = "Melisa Mayer", Year = 1968 });
        list1.Patients.Add(new Patient { ID = 33, Name = "Morgan Smith", Year = 1979 });

        var root = new TreeViewModel();
        root.Add(list1);
        Tree.Add(root);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> Tree { get; set; }
}
```

TreeViewModel class:

```
public class TreeViewModel
{
    public TreeViewModel()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>();
        Title = "Patients"; // Root node name
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> Children { get; }

    public void Add(PatientsList list)
    {
        foreach (var i in list.Patients)
        {
            var child = new TreeViewModel();
            child.Title = "Patient"; // Level2 node name
            child.Add(i);
            Children.Add(child);
        }

    }

    private void Add(Patient patient)
    {
        Add($"ID: {patient.ID}");
        Add($"Name: {patient.Name}");
        Add($"Year: {patient.Year}");
    }

    private void Add(string title)
    {
        Children.Add(new TreeViewModel { Title = title });
    }
}
```